# Can't import win32crypt python module

Tags: windows, dll, pywin32, python-3.4

I have the 32 bit version of python 3.4 installed. I'm trying to use the win32crypt module after installing [pywin32](https://sourceforge.net/projects/pywin32/files/) but I get the following error message in git CLI:

`import win32crypt
ImportError: DLL load failed: The specified module could not be found.`

As recommended[here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/3956576/3091219), I used dependency walker on the win32crypt.pyd file (located at C://Python34/Libsite-packages/win32 on my computer) and several dll are missing: PYTHON34.dll, PYWINTYPES34.DLL, GPSVC.DLL, IESHIMS.DLL.

Are these missing dll likely to cause the import failure? If so, how can I fix this?

Answer (score 6):

A more modern solution:

`pip install pypiwin32`

This contains .whl files to aid in installing on Windows.

Answer (score 4):

You don't need to copy/paste any dll, simply add the pywin32 module to the windows environment variable Path. Default is: "C:\Python34\Lib\site-packages\pywin32_system32".

Please note that dependency walker still shows missing dll, so maybe it is of doubtful utility in some cases.

Answer (score 0):

I try to use python x64, and it work.

Answer (score -1):

another solution is that you can copy 2 dll files from "C:\Python34\Lib\site-packages\pywin32_system32" and paste them where ur .py file location is，and then use the command --add-data ".*.dll;." just make sure there're no more dll files but these two in this path. this is suitable when you are using '-F' command