# The pip commands to install modules are not working

Tags: python, python-3.x, module, pywin32

I have use the pip commands to install win32crypt, but when I execute the code the I get this error

```
Message=No module named 'win32crypt'
```

Source=C:\Users\sheaf\source\repos\Password Puller\Password Puller\Password_Puller.py
StackTrace:
File "C:\Users\sheaf\source\repos\Password Puller\Password Puller\Password_Puller.py", line 5, in  (Current frame)
import win32crypt

I have tried this on Python 3.7 32 bit, 3.7 64 bit, and 3.9 64 bit and none of them work. Below is the code I am trying to execute.

```
import os
import json
import base64
import sqlite3
import win32crypt
from Cryptodome.Cipher import AES
import shutil
from datetime import timezone, datetime, timedelta


def chrome_date_and_time(chrome_data):
    # Chrome_data format is 'year-month-date
    # hr:mins:seconds.milliseconds
    # This will return datetime.datetime Object
    return datetime(1601, 1, 1) + timedelta(microseconds=chrome_data)


def fetching_encryption_key():
    # Local_computer_directory_path will look
    # like this below
    # C: => Users => <Your_Name> => AppData =>
    # Local => Google => Chrome => User Data =>
    # Local State
    local_computer_directory_path = os.path.join(
    os.environ["USERPROFILE"], "AppData", "Local", "Google", "Chrome",
    "User Data", "Local State")
    
    with open(local_computer_directory_path, "r", encoding="utf-8") as f:
        local_state_data = f.read()
        local_state_data = json.loads(local_state_data)

    # decoding the encryption key using base64
    encryption_key = base64.b64decode(
    local_state_data["os_crypt"]["encrypted_key"])
    
    # remove Windows Data Protection API (DPAPI) str
    encryption_key = encryption_key[5:]
    
    # return decrypted key
    return win32crypt.CryptUnprotectData(encryption_key, None, None, None, 0)[1]


def password_decryption(password, encryption_key):
    try:
        iv = password[3:15]
        password = password[15:]
        
        # generate cipher
        cipher = AES.new(encryption_key, AES.MODE_GCM, iv)
        
        # decrypt password
        return cipher.decrypt(password)[:-16].decode()
    except:
        
        try:
            return str(win32crypt.CryptUnprotectData(password, None, None, None, 0)[1])
        except:
            return "No Passwords"


def main():
    key = fetching_encryption_key()
    db_path = os.path.join(os.environ["USERPROFILE"], "AppData", "Local",
                        "Google", "Chrome", "User Data", "default", "Login Data")
    filename = "ChromePasswords.db"
    shutil.copyfile(db_path, filename)
    
    # connecting to the database
    db = sqlite3.connect(filename)
    cursor = db.cursor()
    
    # 'logins' table has the data
    cursor.execute(
        "select origin_url, action_url, username_value, password_value, date_created, date_last_used from logins "
        "order by date_last_used")
    
    # iterate over all rows
    for row in cursor.fetchall():
        main_url = row[0]
        login_page_url = row[1]
        user_name = row[2]
        decrypted_password = password_decryption(row[3], key)
        date_of_creation = row[4]
        last_usuage = row[5]
        
        if user_name or decrypted_password:
            print(f"Main URL: {main_url}")
            print(f"Login URL: {login_page_url}")
            print(f"User name: {user_name}")
            print(f"Decrypted Password: {decrypted_password}")
        
        else:
            continue
        
        if date_of_creation != 86400000000 and date_of_creation:
            print(f"Creation date: {str(chrome_date_and_time(date_of_creation))}")
        
        if last_usuage != 86400000000 and last_usuage:
            print(f"Last Used: {str(chrome_date_and_time(last_usuage))}")
        print("=" * 100)
    cursor.close()
    db.close()
    
    try:
        
        # trying to remove the copied db file as
        # well from local computer
        os.remove(filename)
    except:
        pass


if __name__ == "__main__":
    main()
```

Comment: I found this post that might help: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23406654/cant-import-win32crypt-python-module

Comment: I was able to use pip install pywin32 and run the code from here w/ no issues: https://github.com/mhammond/pywin32/blob/e0a7d99d7fe770e6eda58c1fa0988e7cc48f9b97/win32/test/test_win32crypt.py

Comment: i need more help please contact my discord Bumbling_Yeti#0212

Comment: It seems possible that you have python environment issues.  Have you checked that the code is running against the same python environment that your pip installation points to?